# Is it possible for a single object to have more than one mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects, parent

I have two objects, *A* and *B*, each with their own meshes. Is it possible to take the mesh of *A* and put it inside *B* but still keeping it separate from the original mesh of *A*? How can this be done?

For elaboration, please see the image below:

[image: This is what I want to accomplish.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't give one object two mesh datablocks at once.

However, if you need to do something like packing UVs of two meshes together you can assign a vertex group to all the vertices in the active mesh. Then you should join the meshes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), do the unwrap or whatever you needed to do, deselect everything, select the vertices in the group, and separate them (<kbd>P</kbd> *> Selection*). That way you have your original object back, but unwrapped together. The [Texture Atlas](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas) addon can also do this.

If you need to move two meshes together, [parent](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/parents.html) them both to an *[Empty](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/empties.html)* ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).